# calling rest apis from tradingview

Tags: email, binance

What I need to do is to tie Tradingview alert system to the api of a Crypto Exchange. I know Tradingview offers alerts that can be sent via SMS or EMail - but - how can I convert this info so that I can call the APIs of a Crypto Currency exchange.

For example, if I create an alert to buy a certain ICO at a specified price, then what I need is some way to get this to trigger ~something~ (a PHP script or whatever) that will go ahead an execute the REST command that will create an order on Binance or Bittrex or ....

Any info, hacks or ideas on how this could be done would be GREATLY appreciated. If there is something better that can be used, let me know that as well.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

You could use email alerts and then periodically fetch email (i.e. with a PHP script).

Then when you receive a Tradingview alert from this email address you can start your background process (buy or sell with markets api).

Comment: I know this is old - but - Tradingview now allows one to execute REST APIs. If a condition is met on a Chart, then a "message" can be sent to a REST API (that you create) for processing : https://www.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/

Comment: @CaseyHarrils is this api only for brokers?

Comment: @Luther - no, anyone can use it